# Kafka offset lag falls far behind reason?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We have been trying to fix our consumer that does not want to consume data.
It polls every 4 seconds and usually only receives about 100 records. Max it pulls about 18000. Then it writes raw bytes to a file. All quick operations.

But consumer group call shows the following

```
[xyz@AZ254PP01 kafka]$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --new-consumer --group postproc-red2
GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER
postproc-red2, targeting-seg, 0, 21921226, 21921388, 162, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-visit, 0, 72891022, 78349037, 5458015, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-vis, 0, 16665679, 18122272, 1456593, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-vc, 0, 50847858, 56468186, 5620328, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-seg, 1, 20733636, 24858954, 4125318, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-visit, 1, 75084847, 89556283, 14471436, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-vis, 1, 19648100, 19648100, 0, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-vc, 1, 66549015, 66549015, 0, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-seg, 2, 24903106, 28041684, 3138578, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-visit, 2, 99480656, 99480656, 0, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-vis, 2, 19982077, 24848188, 4866111, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
postproc-red2, targeting-vc, 2, 69611742, 76253273, 6641531, consumer-2_/192.168.201.121
```

When it logs it seems to only want to consume from targeting-seg-0 but only 60-90 records at a time. It sometimes pulls from all 0 partitions a few thousand at once. The data just makes no sense what soever and we are at a loss when it comes to where else to look for the issue.
It is only one consumer. One process that consumes all the partitions of those topics.

The producer for the last two days only seems to write to the 0 partitions. And we don't know the reason for that either.

I tried just to see if it works to seekToEnd on all partitions that did not get pulled from for more than 60 seconds.

```
14:58:33.896 [Kafka-0] INFO  c.t.e.p.s.red2.ConsumerService - Processing records 3263 of Topics [targeting-seg-0, targeting-visit-0, targeting-vis-0, targeting-vc-0]
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-seg-1
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-visit-2
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-seg-2
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-visit-1
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-vis-1
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-vis-2
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-vc-1
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-vc-2
14:58:38.005 [Kafka-0] INFO  c.t.e.p.s.red2.ConsumerService - Processing records 3284 of Topics [targeting-seg-0, targeting-visit-0, targeting-vis-0, targeting-vc-0]
14:58:42.117 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-seg-1
14:58:42.117 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-visit-2
14:58:42.117 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-seg-2
14:58:42.117 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-visit-1
14:58:42.117 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-vis-1
14:58:42.117 [Kafka-0] INFO  com.twyn.service.kafka.KafkaService - Initiated Seek to END for targeting-vis-2
```

code was subscribe(topics). poll(500). seekToEnd.
and then I was hoping it on the next poll the seekToEnd would fix a problematic offsetcommit.

Any ideas what the problem of the Kafka setup might be or how to fix it.
It pretty much runs on default settings. None of the partitions have a replica -> replication-factor 1. We intend to switch to replication factor 3 as the producers are three servers.

Answer (score 0):

Producer choose the target partition based on the hash of the key of the message that it is going to "produce". You should check if messages in the last two days have always the same key.

On the consumer side are you sure that the postproc-red2 is used only for this consumer? Are you sure to have unique consumer id within the same group?
Hovewer best practice is to have consumer number equal to partition number of the source topic.

Hope this can help